# Transition and blur filter not working together properly on iPad with IOS8

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, transition, blur

**What I want:**

What I want to do is give a div, footer and navigation a blury effect after clicking on an button (image). But at the same time I want a popup to appear **with transition** from the top of the screen. Everything works fine on pc or mac.

**Problem:**

On the iPad: After clicking the button the screen pauzes for a moment, the blurry effect is added and then the popup appears **without the transition** on the screen.

How can I get the result that works for pc or mac on an iPad. Can someone help me?

**JS:**

```
function showPopup(selector){
   $(selector).transition({top: -75});
   $('#content').css({"background":"rgba(0,0,0,0.4)"});
   $("div#content, footer, div#navigation").addClass("blur");
}
```

**CSS**

```
.blur{
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
 /*************SOLUTION***************/
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 /************************************/
}
```

I'm using [jquery.transit.js](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) for the transition and IOS8 (8.1.2) is installed on my iPad.

Comment: Please also include the iOS version and a link to the transition plugin you used

Comment: I don't see the use of top anywhere on the link you gave, it could be that the plugin will default to .animation() and not use css transitions? could you please check on the your computer? that may be the cause of the problem. This is under the category of *old browsers* but still fits your description about the lack of animation *Transit degrades older browsers by simply not doing the transformations (rotate, scale, etc) while still doing standard CSS (opacity, marginLeft, etc) without any animation*. IOS8 bug maybe?

Comment: You might want to make some transition tests on a very simple test page. Then you could say for sure if it's the plugin, some code on your website (that freeze bothers me) or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution here: http://indiegamr.com/ios6-html-hardware-acceleration-changes-and-how-to-fix-them/

I added this:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: I honestly cannot believe that this is still an issue after 7 bloody years.